# PHP matching entered text field value to my preferred keywords

Tags: php, html

I want a quick search on my website. If a value is entered and matched with my preferred keywords, it will redirect you to that page.

So far this is what I got:

```
<form method="get" action="redirect.php" > 
<input id="search" name="search" type="text" value="Search Here" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>


<?php

 if(isset($_GET['submit']));

 $product1_keywords = array('animal feeds', 'weanrite', 'Wean Rite');
 // my preffered keywords


 $search = $_GET['search'];
 // caller of entered value on text field  ???


if ($search = $product1_keywords) {
// if value of text field is matched with my preferred keywords


    // Redirect page if match
header('Location: http://localhost/equalivet_2/#products/wean_rite.html');
}

else {

// Redirect page if not match
header('Location: http://localhost/equalivet_2/not_found.html');
}

    ?>
```

Help me please. Thank you.

Comment: you compare using == operator .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `in_array` which you would use like this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['submit']));

$product1_keywords = array('animal feeds', 'weanrite', 'Wean Rite');
// my preferred keywords

$search = $_GET['search']; 
// caller of entered value on text field  ???

if(in_array($search , $product1_keywords)) {

  // if value of text field is matched with my preferred keywords

  // Redirect page if match
  header('Location: http://localhost/equalivet_2/#products/wean_rite.html');

} else {

  // Redirect page if not match
  header('Location: http://localhost/equalivet_2/not_found.html');

}

?>
```

Comment: Yes sir, It works Now , Thank you very much!   I accepted your answer but I can't add Rep because I'm not allowed (requires 15 Rep points)..

Comment: I have a problem now..  I have 10 products and I'm repeating this function for other products but the function detected was the last function for that product..  any idea what should I do?

Comment: @DaniloLizada - I think your best bet is to write a new question. I'll take a look at it and I'm sure other will to. It would be bad of me to answer a new question in comments like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in_array function of php , look at this link 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use `in_array()` function to search whether input provided matches with list of keyword specified by you.

[in_array — Checks if a value exists in an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: yes I tried it though before, this is what i did:  if(in_array($_GET['search'] = $product1_keywords))        but now I got it right this time

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `in_array` to check with search text

```
<?php

 if(isset($_GET['submit']));

 $product1_keywords = array('animal feeds', 'weanrite', 'Wean Rite');
 // my preffered keywords


 $search = $_GET['search'];
 // caller of entered value on text field  ???


if(in_array($search , $product1_keywords)) {
// if value of text field is matched with my preferred keywords


    // Redirect page if match
header('Location: http://localhost/equalivet_2/#products/wean_rite.html');
}

else {

// Redirect page if not match
header('Location: http://localhost/equalivet_2/not_found.html');
}

    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you ! just a minute awat from Erik'sanswer , but still hanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a logic-issue on this line:

```
if ($search = $product1_keywords) {
```

It should be `==` instead of `=`; however, this does not answer your question.

If I understand correctly, you simply want to redirect the user based on a keyword they entered. I would recommend updating your *keywords* array to have the keywords and the URLs you want to redirect the user to all-in-one:

```
$product1_keywords = array(
    'animal feeds' => '/url1',
    'weanrite' => '/url2',
    'wean rite' => '/url3'
);
```

Then, loop through this and check the keywords entered (ignoring any case):

```
$search = strtolower($_GET['search']);
foreach ($product1_keywords as $keyword => $url) {
    if ($search == $keyword) {
        // we found a keyword match!
        header($url);
        die();
    }
}
// if it makes it here, they didn't match a keyword
header('/not-found.html');
die();
```

If all of the keywords go to the same URL, you can either set them all to the same URL in the `$product1_keywords` array - *or* - you can use PHP's [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array) method for a quicker lookup:

```
$search = strtolower($_GET['search']);
$url = in_array($search, $product1_keywords) ? '/url-found' : '/not-found.html';
header($url);
die();
```

Comment: Thanks sir but I will use multiple keywords for one product not just one word.  but thanks I may be using your answer for my future projects. Kudos!

Comment: @DaniloLizada The second part of my answer, using `in_array()`, would work for multiple-keywords for one product (I see several other users posted the same method too though).

Comment: Sir I have a problem now.. I have 10 products and I'm repeating the function but the only working function was the last function for that item only

Comment: @DaniloLizada Sorry, but I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for. You may have to post a code-example for clarification; as you've already marked this question as answered, this may constitute posting a new question (if it requires a different/new answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
<?php
$test1 = "hi";
$test2 = array("hi","hello");

for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($test2);$i++)
{
similar_text($test1, $test2[$i], $percent); 
    if($percent==100)
        echo "Match found";
}
```

?>

Comment: I am not giving you complete solution work on this code. You will find your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.

I add the solution if you have multiple products:

```
 <?php

 if(isset($_GET['submit']));


 $product1_keywords = array('feeds', 'weanrite', 'Wean Rite');

 $product2_keywords = array('gro rite', 'Gro Rite', 'grorite', 'growing feeds');

 $product3_keywords = array('rite start', 'Rite Start', 'starter feed');



 $search = $_GET['search']; 
  // caller of entered value on text field  ???


  if(in_array($search , $product1_keywords)) {

    // if value of text field is matched with my preferred keywords

    // Redirect page if match
   header('Location: http://localhost/equalivet_2/#products/wean_rite.html');

  } 

  elseif(in_array($search , $product2_keywords)) {

  header('Location: http://localhost/equalivet_2/#products/gro_rite.html');

  }
  elseif(in_array($search , $product3_keywords)) {

  header('Location: http://localhost/equalivet_2/#products/rite_start.html');

  }



  else {

 // Redirect page if not match
  header('Location: http://localhost/equalivet_2/equalivet/not_found.html');

  }

  die;
  ?>
```

Thank you. And I hope this will help those who might need this post